# Trouble with infinite sums approximations with different integers in Python

Tags: python, math

I am very new to Python but I wanted to try answering a math problem involving if there's a value of p for which the sum from n=1 to infinity of 2/p^n - 1/n^p has any results that are zero. I planned to do this by letting Python loop through values of p from 1 to 10 and for each of those doing a sum from n=1 to n=10 (to approximate infinite sums, but I would try 100 if I could get it to work.

So I created an empty list to add all of these additions to, then ideally I could do

```
print(summations.append(0))
```

to find the right value of p. But for some reason my code just returns an empty list. Anyone know what I could be doing wrong? Would greatly appreciate it! Here's my code:

```
from fractions import Fraction
from decimal import Decimal


n = 1.0
p = 1.0

def s12():
    summations = []
    s = 10
    r = Fraction(2,p**n) - Fraction(1,n**p)
    while p <= s and n <= s:
            n += 1.0
            r += (Fraction(2,p**n) - Fraction(1,n**p))         
    else:
        summations.append(Decimal(r.numerator)/Decimal(r.denominator))
        n -= (s-1)
        p += 1
    return summations



print(summations)
```

And when I run it I just get:

```
[]
```

Comment: You should get a `NameError`, because `summations` is a local variable and does not exist after you call `s12`. (For that matter, where *do* you call `s12`?)

Comment: `n` and `p` should both be initialized *inside* `s12` as well. The code as shown will produce an `UnboundLocalError` the first time you try compare `n <= s`, because the *local* variable `n` (which results from the assignment statement `n += 1.0`) does not yet exist.

Comment: Try “print(s12())”

Comment: Dylan, it looks like you are doing some good work, but the approach you are taking can't really work right. An infinite sum can be very different from any finite sum of a subset of the terms. I think you should look at this differently. You can figure out an exact result for the summation of 2/p^n -- it is a geometric sum. 1/n^p is a little more obscure -- the result is the so-called Riemann zeta function if I'm not mistaken. Then the question is, for what values of p is the result from the geometric sum equal to the Riemann zeta function? Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following improvement to posted code

- Create interpolate for p basic Python functions
- Fractions not recommended since best value of p is a non-integer
- Not clear what you were after with a while-else
- Decimal is not recommended since we don't need the precision
- Sum 100 values rather than 10 for better precision

**Code**

```
def calc(n, p):
  """
    Calculates basic term as a function of n & p
    Fraction not recommended since we need p to be non-integer to find the best value 
  """
  return 2/p**n - 1/n**p

def calc_sum(p):
  " Calculate sum of 100 terms for a given p "
  return sum(calc(n, p) for n in range(1, 100))

def float_range(start, stop, step):
  " Generate a floating point range to interpolate p "
  result = []
  while start < stop:
    result.append(start)
    start += step
  return result
```

**Finding best p value**

Try p between 1 and 5

```
for p in float_range(1, 5, .`5):
  print(p, calc_sum(p))
```

*Output--tells us p is between 2 and 2.5*

```
1 192.82262248236043
1.5 1.588125901296283
2.0 0.36511609981510706
2.5 -0.007482236418130598
3.0 -0.20200640065967757
3.5 -0.32672981702540194
4.0 -0.4156562286778066
4.5 -0.48327891025770453
```

*Try p between 2 and 2.5*

```
for p in float_range(2.0, 2.6, .1):
  print(p, calc_sum(p))

2.0 0.36511609981510706
2.1 0.26373291881978755
2.2 0.17946094825759307
2.3000000000000003 0.10798856705365398
2.4000000000000004 0.04636859245977225
2.5000000000000004 -0.007482236418130978
```

*We see p is between 2.4 and 2.5*

```
for p in float_range(2.4, 2.6, .01):
  print(p, calc_sum(p))

2.4 0.046368592459772415
2.4099999999999997 0.04066262119862629
2.4199999999999995 0.035032169029363944
2.4299999999999993 0.029475572173387914
2.439999999999999 0.023991217574155975
2.449999999999999 0.01857754094561895
2.4599999999999986 0.013233024909891436
2.4699999999999984 0.007956197219502172
2.479999999999998 0.0027456290598434226
2.489999999999998 -0.0024000665723135266
2.499999999999998 -0.007482236418129554
2.5099999999999976 -0.01250218843750795
2.5199999999999974 -0.017461193224867975
2.529999999999997 -0.02236048536315304
2.539999999999997 -0.027201264719155526
2.5499999999999967 -0.03198469768307924
2.5599999999999965 -0.036711918355086776
2.5699999999999963 -0.041384029681439
2.579999999999996 -0.04600210454268127
2.589999999999996 -0.05056718679620625
2.5999999999999956 -0.05508029227539101
```

*So p is between 2.47899999 and 2.499999*